# If conditions using regex

Tags: java, regex

What regex would help satisfy the following situation:

```
if (string starts with a letter (one or more))
  it must be followed by a . or _ (not both)
else
  no match
```

Example (imagine i have a list of values to be matched, that are being tested):

```
public static boolean matches(String k) {

    for (final String key : protectedKeys) {

        final String OPTIONAL_SEPARATOR = "[\\._]?";
        final String OPTIONAL_CHARACTERS = "(?:[a-zA-Z]+)?";
        final String OR = "|";

        final String SEPARATED = OPTIONAL_CHARACTERS + 
                  OPTIONAL_SEPARATOR + key + OPTIONAL_SEPARATOR
                + OPTIONAL_CHARACTERS;

        String pattern = "(" + key + OR + SEPARATED + ")";

        if (k.matches(pattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code matches all of the below

```
    System.out.println(matches("usr"));

    System.out.println(matches("_usr"));
    System.out.println(matches("system_usr"));
    System.out.println(matches(".usr"));
    System.out.println(matches("system.usr"));

    System.out.println(matches("usr_"));
    System.out.println(matches("usr_system"));
    System.out.println(matches("usr."));
    System.out.println(matches("usr.system"));

    System.out.println(matches("_usr_"));
    System.out.println(matches("system_usr_production"));
    System.out.println(matches(".usr."));
    System.out.println(matches("system.usr.production"));
```

But fails on

```
    System.out.println(matches("weirdusr")); // matches when it should not
```

Simplified, i'd like to recognize that

```
        final String a = "(?:[a-zA-Z]+)[\\._]" + key;
        final String b = "^[\\._]?" + key;
```

When string starts with a character, separator is no longer optional, else, if string starts with the a separator, it is now optional

Comment: +1 for test cases! Why is "usr" a good match, but "weirdusr" is not? Both start with a letter, and both are not followed by "." or "_".

Comment: `usr` is a good match because it's a standalone (and is listed in protectedKeys). `weirduser` is not listed in protectedKeys

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy the mentioned condition, try:

```
srt.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(\\.[^_]?|_[^\\.]?)[^\\._]*")
```

Comment: This does not pass all the test cases

Comment: In the Sysouts that you mentioned, some cases starts with a dot or a _, hence the condition where a String need to start with a letter don't works... I guess i don't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work as well, if this helps to anyone

```
    for (final String key : protectedKeys) {

        final String separator = "[\\._]";
        final String textSeparator = "(" + "^(?:[a-zA-Z]+)" + separator + ")";
        final String separatorText = "(?:" + separator + "(?:[a-zA-Z]+)$" + ")";

        final String OR = "|";

        final String azWithSeparator = textSeparator + "?" + key + separatorText + "?";
        final String optionalSeparatorWithoutAZ = separator + "?" + key + separator + "?";

        String pattern = "(" + key + OR + azWithSeparator + OR + optionalSeparatorWithoutAZ + ")";

        if (k.matches(pattern)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fyi, it would most likely be better to join all the `protectedKeys` (with `|`) and use that in a single expression which you execute once, and not as now, for every keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string starts with a letter (one or more))
  it must be followed by a . or _ (not both)
else
  no match
```

Can be written with regex as:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[._]
```

The regex is made to spec (you do not say anything about what is allowed to follow).

The match will fail per definition if the condition is not met, thus no need for any `else` alteration with a forced fail `(?!)`.